# Angular 8 get request : header is sent nulll

Tags: angular, authentication, jwt

```
  jwt = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
  getAllQueryLogs() {
    return this.http.get(localUrl + 'reports/logs', {headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.jwt
      })});
  }
```

I am trying to send a bearer jwt for a get request. But the header is null when I debug my application. Could you tell me the problem please? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided should work though. I guess you either imported something HTTP related from a wrong package, or you have some HttpInterceptor that deletes these headers. I created a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gu9lx3) that shows the code is indeed working.

Comment: But when I check in chrome network tab, headers I pass do not appear

Comment: On this StackBlitz they do. Or do they not appear for you there either?

Comment: I can indeed see the Authorization in your example, but when I make the get request, I do not see it unfortunately

Comment: As already stated in my answer: Did you make sure that you imported everything from the correct package (`@angular/common/http`)? Are any HTTPInterceptors set up that might interfere with your Headers? Can you maybe post the whole Service your code snipped is taken from?

Comment: I realized that even though I am calling a http.get method, it is converted to an Options request.  Can it be the reason?

Comment: Yep, options won't carry your headers. That is a preflight request.

Comment: Thank you, Options requests are blocked by default in spring boot security. I did not know that. When option fails, it does not send the desired post reqeust at all

Comment: Indeed, easiest solution would be to either use a proxy when developing locally, effectively serving your application and the spring boot endpoint via the same domain. Or you enable CORS in Spring Boot :)